# Get first and second highest values in pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am using pandas to analyse some election results. I have a DF, Results, which has a row for each constituency and columns representing the votes for the various parties (over 100 of them):

```
In[60]: Results.columns
Out[60]: 
Index(['Constituency', 'Region', 'Country', 'ID', 'Type', 'Electorate',
       'Total', 'Unnamed: 9', '30-50', 'Above',
       ...
       'WP', 'WRP', 'WVPTFP', 'Yorks', 'Young', 'Zeb', 'Party', 'Votes',
       'Share', 'Turnout'],
      dtype='object', length=147)
```

So...

```
In[63]: Results.head()
Out[63]: 
                         Constituency    Region   Country         ID    Type  \
PAID                                                                           
1                            Aberavon     Wales     Wales  W07000049  County   
2                           Aberconwy     Wales     Wales  W07000058  County   
3                      Aberdeen North  Scotland  Scotland  S14000001   Burgh   
4                      Aberdeen South  Scotland  Scotland  S14000002   Burgh   
5     Aberdeenshire West & Kincardine  Scotland  Scotland  S14000058  County   

      Electorate  Total  Unnamed: 9  30-50  Above    ...     WP  WRP  WVPTFP  \
PAID                                                 ...                       
1          49821  31523         NaN    NaN    NaN    ...    NaN  NaN     NaN   
2          45525  30148         NaN    NaN    NaN    ...    NaN  NaN     NaN   
3          67745  43936         NaN    NaN    NaN    ...    NaN  NaN     NaN   
4          68056  48551         NaN    NaN    NaN    ...    NaN  NaN     NaN   
5          73445  55196         NaN    NaN    NaN    ...    NaN  NaN     NaN   

      Yorks  Young  Zeb  Party  Votes     Share   Turnout  
PAID                                                       
1       NaN    NaN  NaN    Lab  15416  0.489040  0.632725  
2       NaN    NaN  NaN    Con  12513  0.415052  0.662230  
3       NaN    NaN  NaN    SNP  24793  0.564298  0.648550  
4       NaN    NaN  NaN    SNP  20221  0.416490  0.713398  
5       NaN    NaN  NaN    SNP  22949  0.415773  0.751528  

[5 rows x 147 columns]
```

The per-constituency results for each party are given in the columns `Results.ix[:, 'Unnamed: 9': 'Zeb']`

I can find the winning party (i.e. the party which polled highest number of votes) and the number of votes it polled using:

```
RawResults = Results.ix[:, 'Unnamed: 9': 'Zeb']
Results['Party'] = RawResults.idxmax(axis=1)
Results['Votes'] = RawResults.max(axis=1).astype(int)
```

But, I also need to know how many votes the second-place party got (and ideally its index/name). So is there any way in pandas to return the *second* highest value/index in a set of columns for each row?

Comment: See [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html).

Comment: @AmiTavory Surely df.nlargest(column) will return the n larges values in a column, whereas I want to do it across a row?

Comment: Then use [`transpose`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)?

Comment: @AmiTavory, it's a right direction (i guess), but it's bit tricky and might be difficult...

Comment: I feel like this question is titled differently from the content. The title is asking for the 2 largest values in each column, but the content is asking for the 2 highest values in each row.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To get the highest values of a column you can use [nlargest()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) :

```
df['High'].nlargest(2)
```

The above will give you the 2 **highest** values of column `High`.

---

You can also use [nsmallest()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nsmallest.html) to get the **lowest** values.

Comment: What if I want to have the first and second high of SEVERAL columns (let me make the example with just two columns, for simplicity). For only the highest (max) I can simply do `df['col1', 'col2'].agg([sum, max])` but that does not work with nlargest, which wants to keep the other elements of the column intact, rather than discarding them as max does.

Comment: @Davide You should create a new question.

Comment: `df.nlargest(2, 'High')` might be useful if you want to display other columns too

Answer (score 22):

Here is a NumPy solution:

```
In [120]: df
Out[120]:
          a         b         c         d         e         f         g         h
0  1.334444  0.322029  0.302296 -0.841236 -0.360488 -0.860188 -0.157942  1.522082
1  2.056572  0.991643  0.160067 -0.066473  0.235132  0.533202  1.282371 -2.050731
2  0.955586 -0.966734  0.055210 -0.993924 -0.553841  0.173793 -0.534548 -1.796006
3  1.201001  1.067291 -0.562357 -0.794284 -0.554820 -0.011836  0.519928  0.514669
4 -0.243972 -0.048144  0.498007  0.862016  1.284717 -0.886455 -0.757603  0.541992
5  0.739435 -0.767399  1.574173  1.197063 -1.147961 -0.903858  0.011073 -1.404868
6 -1.258282 -0.049719  0.400063  0.611456  0.443289 -1.110945  1.352029  0.215460
7  0.029121 -0.771431 -0.285119 -0.018216  0.408425 -1.458476 -1.363583  0.155134
8  1.427226 -1.005345  0.208665 -0.674917  0.287929 -1.259707  0.220420 -1.087245
9  0.452589  0.214592 -1.875423  0.487496  2.411265  0.062324 -0.327891  0.256577

In [121]: np.sort(df.values)[:,-2:]
Out[121]:
array([[ 1.33444404,  1.52208164],
       [ 1.28237078,  2.05657214],
       [ 0.17379254,  0.95558613],
       [ 1.06729107,  1.20100071],
       [ 0.86201603,  1.28471676],
       [ 1.19706331,  1.57417327],
       [ 0.61145573,  1.35202868],
       [ 0.15513379,  0.40842477],
       [ 0.28792928,  1.42722604],
       [ 0.48749578,  2.41126532]])
```

or as a pandas Data Frame:

```
In [122]: pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values)[:,-2:], columns=['2nd-largest','largest'])
Out[122]:
   2nd-largest   largest
0     1.334444  1.522082
1     1.282371  2.056572
2     0.173793  0.955586
3     1.067291  1.201001
4     0.862016  1.284717
5     1.197063  1.574173
6     0.611456  1.352029
7     0.155134  0.408425
8     0.287929  1.427226
9     0.487496  2.411265
```

or a [faster solution from @Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066260/get-first-and-second-highest-values-in-pandas-columns/39067057?noredirect=1#comment65482994_39067057):

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
          a         b         c         d         e         f         g         h
0  0.649517 -0.223116  0.264734 -1.121666  0.151591 -1.335756 -0.155459 -2.500680
1  0.172981  1.233523  0.220378  1.188080 -0.289469 -0.039150  1.476852  0.736908
2 -1.904024  0.109314  0.045741 -0.341214 -0.332267 -1.363889  0.177705 -0.892018
3 -2.606532 -0.483314  0.054624  0.979734  0.205173  0.350247 -1.088776  1.501327
4  1.627655 -1.261631  0.589899 -0.660119  0.742390 -1.088103  0.228557  0.714746
5  0.423972 -0.506975 -0.783718 -2.044002 -0.692734  0.980399  1.007460  0.161516
6 -0.777123 -0.838311 -1.116104 -0.433797  0.599724 -0.884832 -0.086431 -0.738298
7  1.131621  1.218199  0.645709  0.066216 -0.265023  0.606963 -0.194694  0.463576
8  0.421164  0.626731 -0.547738  0.989820 -1.383061 -0.060413 -1.342769 -0.777907
9 -1.152690  0.696714 -0.155727 -0.991975 -0.806530  1.454522  0.788688  0.409516

In [7]: a = df.values

In [8]: a[np.arange(len(df))[:,None],np.argpartition(-a,np.arange(2),axis=1)[:,:2]]
Out[8]:
array([[ 0.64951665,  0.26473378],
       [ 1.47685226,  1.23352348],
       [ 0.17770473,  0.10931398],
       [ 1.50132666,  0.97973383],
       [ 1.62765464,  0.74238959],
       [ 1.00745981,  0.98039898],
       [ 0.5997243 , -0.0864306 ],
       [ 1.21819904,  1.13162068],
       [ 0.98982033,  0.62673128],
       [ 1.45452173,  0.78868785]])
```

Comment: It works, but only after I converted the NaNs to zeros.

Comment: @TimGJ `np.argparition` seems to work well with `NaNs`. For the conversion from `NaNs` to `0s`, `np.where` could be used.

Comment: @TimGJ Or a hacky method without converting to zeros : `-np.sort(-df.values)[:,:2]`.

Answer (score 3):

You could just sort your results, such that the first rows will contain the max. Then you can simply use indexing to get the first n places.

```
RawResults = Results.ix[:, 'Unnamed: 9': 'Zeb'].sort_values(by='votes', ascending=False)
RawResults.iloc[0, :] # First place
RawResults.iloc[1, :] # Second place
RawResults.iloc[n, :] # nth place
```

Comment: Note that this solution has superlinear complexity, whereas it can be done in linear time.

Comment: I'm not sure that will work. There is no guarantee that the maximum value will always be in the same column.

Comment: I misread your question. Sorry about the lousy answer. I did not realise each row is a constituency, and you want the highest column across the rows. I did consider a solution with Numpy as that would be faster, but I did not want to complicate things.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an interesting approach. What if we replace the maximum value with the minimum value and calculate. Although it is a quick hack and, not recommended!

```
first_highest_value_index = df.idxmax()
second_highest_value_index = df.replace(df.max(),df(min)).idxmax()

first_highest_value = df[first_highest_value_index]
second_highest_value = df[second_highest_value_index]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using **nlargest** function:

```
>>> df
    a   b   c
 0  4  20   2
 1  5  10   2
 2  3  40   5
 3  1  50  10
 4  2  30  15
>>> def give_largest(col,n):
...     largest = col.nlargest(n).reset_index(drop = True)
...     data = [x for x in largest]
...     index = [f'{i}_largest' for i in range(1,len(largest)+1)]
...     return pd.Series(data,index=index)
...
...
>>> def n_largest(df, axis, n):
...     '''
...     Function to return the n-largest value of each
...     column/row of the input DataFrame.
...     '''
...     return df.apply(give_largest, axis = axis, n = n)
...
>>> n_largest(df,axis = 1, n = 2)
   1_largest  2_largest
0         20          4
1         10          5
2         40          5
3         50         10
4         30         15
>>> n_largest(df,axis = 0, n = 2)
                  a           b           c     
1_largest         5          50           15
2_largest         4          40           10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [4, 5, 3, 1, 2],
    'b': [20, 10, 40, 50, 30],
    'c': [25, 20, 5, 15, 10]
})
def second_largest(df):
    
    return (df.nlargest(2).min())




print(df.apply(second_largest))
a     4
b    40
c    20
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df
           a           b           c            d           e           f           g          h
0   1.334444    0.322029    0.302296    -0.841236   -0.360488   -0.860188   -0.157942   1.522082
1   2.056572    0.991643    0.160067    -0.066473   0.235132    0.533202    1.282371    -2.050731
2   0.955586    -0.966734   0.055210    -0.993924   -0.553841   0.173793    -0.534548   -1.796006
3   1.201001    1.067291    -0.562357   -0.794284   -0.554820   -0.011836   0.519928    0.514669
4   -0.243972   -0.048144   0.498007    0.862016    1.284717    -0.886455   -0.757603   0.541992
5   0.739435    -0.767399   1.574173    1.197063    -1.147961   -0.903858   0.011073    -1.404868
6   -1.258282   -0.049719   0.400063    0.611456    0.443289    -1.110945   1.352029    0.215460
7   0.029121    -0.771431   -0.285119   -0.018216   0.408425    -1.458476   -1.363583   0.155134
8   1.427226    -1.005345   0.208665    -0.674917   0.287929    -1.259707   0.220420    -1.087245
9   0.452589    0.214592    -1.875423   0.487496    2.411265    0.062324    -0.327891   0.256577
```

tranpose and use nlargest in a for loop to get the results order by each line:

```
df1=df.T
results=list()
for col in df1.columns: results.append(df1[col].nlargest(len(df.columns))
```

the results var is a list of pandas objects, where the first item on the list will be the df's first row sorted in descending order and so on. Since each item on the list is a pandas object, it carries df's column as index (it was transposed), so you will get the values and the df's columns name of each row sorted

```
results
[h    1.522082
 a    1.334444
 b    0.322029
 c    0.302296
 g   -0.157942
 e   -0.360488
 d   -0.841236
 f   -0.860188
 Name: 0, dtype: float64,
 a    2.056572
 g    1.282371
 b    0.991643
 f    0.533202
 e    0.235132
 c    0.160067
 d   -0.066473
 h   -2.050731
 Name: 1, dtype: float64,
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the sort is applied to every column, the index labels will be dropped anyway. We can use `numpy` to achieve this:

```
a=np.random.random([10,4])
a
Out[10]: 
array([[0.11965879, 0.73168303, 0.18521419, 0.13992709],
       [0.8758143 , 0.13136781, 0.22071495, 0.9369399 ],
       [0.9190763 , 0.14320333, 0.66614619, 0.60688266],
       [0.91973194, 0.25297882, 0.02097999, 0.93834247],
       [0.70570349, 0.92229061, 0.64739799, 0.21614292],
       [0.70386848, 0.58542997, 0.78042638, 0.65968369],
       [0.37626386, 0.32668468, 0.42756616, 0.00938118],
       [0.85126718, 0.76305889, 0.03047206, 0.4874788 ],
       [0.88951106, 0.65035676, 0.98210505, 0.35605393],
       [0.96369325, 0.79311159, 0.81995022, 0.10588205]])
np.sort(a, axis=0)
```

We have output:

```
array([[0.11965879, 0.13136781, 0.02097999, 0.00938118],
       [0.37626386, 0.14320333, 0.03047206, 0.10588205],
       [0.70386848, 0.25297882, 0.18521419, 0.13992709],
       [0.70570349, 0.32668468, 0.22071495, 0.21614292],
       [0.85126718, 0.58542997, 0.42756616, 0.35605393],
       [0.8758143 , 0.65035676, 0.64739799, 0.4874788 ],
       [0.88951106, 0.73168303, 0.66614619, 0.60688266],
       [0.9190763 , 0.76305889, 0.78042638, 0.65968369],
       [0.91973194, 0.79311159, 0.81995022, 0.9369399 ],
       [0.96369325, 0.92229061, 0.98210505, 0.93834247]])
```

Here each column is sorted and you can slice the matrix to get the desired values.