# How to get the second largest value in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code:

```
maxData = all_data.groupby(['Id'])[features].agg('max')
all_data = pd.merge(all_data, maxData.reset_index(), suffixes=["", "_max"], how='left', on=['Id'])
```

Now Instead of getting the max value, How can I fetch the second max value in the above code (groupBy Id)

Comment: Check nlargest :https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html

Comment: Maybe find the solution here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066260/get-first-and-second-highest-values-in-pandas-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066260/get-first-and-second-highest-values-in-pandas-columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the nth method just after sorting the values;

```
maxData = all_data.sort_values("features", ascending=False).groupby(['Id']).nth(1)
```

Please ignore apply method as it decreases performance of code.

Comment: It may be any other error. So could you please send me code?

Comment: How do I merge it with all_data?     `all_data = pd.merge(all_data, maxData.reset_index(), suffixes=["", "_secondMax"], how='left', on=['Id'])` gave me this error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'`

Comment: could you please share the original all_data dataframe definition?

Comment: It just contain 310 float columns, and an `Id` column (Id is not unique).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)

```
maxData = all_data.groupby(['Id'])[features].apply(lambda x:x.nlargest(2)[1]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I got this error `TypeError: nlargest() missing 1 required positional argument: 'columns'`