# pyspark dataframe get second lowest value for each row

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I would like to query, if anyone has an idea, how to get the second lowest value in a row of Dataframe in pyspark.

For example:

**Input Dataframe**:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4 
83    32    14    62   
63    32    74    55   
13    88     6    46
```

**Expected output**:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4 Res
83    32    14    62   32   
63    32    74    55   55   
13    88     6    46   13
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43188621/797495

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use **`concat_ws`** function to concat all columns for the row then use **`split`** to create an array.

use **`array_sort`**  function to sort with in the array and extract `second element[1]` of the array.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df=spark.createDataFrame([('83','32','14','62'),('63','32','74','55'),('13','88','6','46')],['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4'])

df.selectExpr("array_sort(split(concat_ws(',',Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4),','))[1] Res").show()

#+---+
#|Res|
#+---+
#|32 |
#|55 |
#|13 |
#+---+
```

**`More Dynamic Way:`**

```
df.selectExpr("array_sort(split(concat_ws(',',*),','))[1]").show()

#+---+
#|Res|
#+---+
#|32 |
#|55 |
#|13 |
#+---+
```

---

**`EDIT:`**

```
#adding Res column to the dataframe
df1=df.selectExpr("*","array_sort(split(concat_ws(',',*),','))[1] Res")
df1.show()

#+----+----+----+----+---+
#|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Res|
#+----+----+----+----+---+
#|  83|  32|  14|  62| 32|
#|  63|  32|  74|  55| 55|
#|  13|  88|   6|  46| 46|
#+----+----+----+----+---+
```

Comment: awesome! do you know how to append new column Res to the dataframe

Comment: @Drachens, Sure!, please check my Updated answer **`EDIT`** section!

Comment: You don't need to concatenate the columns and then split to get an array. You can simply use `array(*cols)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array column using [`array`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array) function and then sort it using [`array_sort`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_sort). Finally, get the second element using [`element_at`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#element_at). These 2 last functions are available from Spark 2.4+.

```
df.withColumn("res", element_at(array_sort(array(*[col(c) for c in df.columns])), 2))\
  .show()

#+----+----+----+----+---+
#|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|res|
#+----+----+----+----+---+
#|83  |32  |14  |62  |32 |
#|63  |32  |74  |55  |55 |
#|13  |88  |6   |46  |13 |
#+----+----+----+----+---+
```

Another way of doing is to use [`least`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#least) function. First, calculate the min value from all columns then calculate another time the least from values that are greater than `min` using `when` expression:

```
df.withColumn("min", least(*[col(c) for c in df.columns]))\
  .withColumn("res", least(*[when(col(c) > col("min"), col(c)) for c in df.columns]))\
  .drop("min")\
  .show()
```