# Get the column names for 2nd largest value for each row in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Say I have such Pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [4, 5, 3, 1, 2],
    'b': [20, 10, 40, 50, 30],
    'c': [25, 20, 5, 15, 10]
})
```

so `df` looks like:

```
print(df)
   a   b   c
0  4  20  25
1  5  10  20
2  3  40   5
3  1  50  15
4  2  30  10
```

And I want to get the column name of the 2nd largest value in each row. Borrowing the answer from Felex Le in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066260/get-first-and-second-highest-values-in-pandas-columns), I can now get the 2nd largest value by:

```
def second_largest(l = []):    
    return (l.nlargest(2).min())

print(df.apply(second_largest, axis = 1))
```

which gives me:

```
0    20
1    10
2     5
3    15
4    10
dtype: int64
```

But what I really want is the column names for those values, or to say:

```
0    b
1    b
2    c
3    c
4    c
```

`Pandas` has a function `idxmax` which can do the job for the largest value:

```
df.idxmax(axis = 1)

0    c
1    c
2    b
3    b
4    b
dtype: object
```

Is there any elegant way to do the same job but for the 2nd largest value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for positions of second largest values:

```
df['new'] = df['new'] = df.columns.to_numpy()[np.argsort(df.to_numpy())[:, -2]]
print(df)
   a   b   c new
0  4  20  25   b
1  5  10  20   b
2  3  40   5   c
3  1  50  15   c
4  2  30  10   c
```

Your solution should working, but is slow:

```
def second_largest(l = []):    
    return (l.nlargest(2).idxmin())

print(df.apply(second_largest, axis = 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

If efficiency is important, [`numpy.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) is quite efficient:

```
N = 2
cols = df.columns.to_numpy()
pd.Series(cols[np.argpartition(df.to_numpy().T, -N, axis=0)[-N]], index=df.index)
```

If you want a pure pandas (less efficient):

```
out = df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda s: s.nlargest(2).index[-1][1])
```

Output:

```
0    b
1    b
2    c
3    c
4    c
dtype: object
```